# Help understanding "Intermediaries" in Bayes rule

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, joint-distribution

I am having trouble with the following equation from Russel and Norvig's AI textbook:

[image: pg 803]

For the first equality, I believe they are converting to joint probability, using marginalization, and then using the chain rule. However, I am not entirely sure where they get the second equality from. When I do it, I don't see how to break up the $ P(X|d,h_i) $ term and I think that is the key issue. Could anyone help with this?

Comment: Welcome to CV! Take a glance at the [self-study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag's wiki and consider adding it to your question. I've answered in the spirit of that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get from the left-most to the middle, consider:

$$P(X|\textbf{d})=\sum_iP(X, h_i|\textbf{d})$$

Tinker with that formula, and you'll get to the middle equation.

To get to the right-most, give a close read of the surrounding context to see if there are any conditional dependency assumptions.

Comment: • Thanks for your answer, I think I see what you're saying. I got the first equality, but for the second equality I just want to confirm that what you're hinting at is the solution is $P(X|d,h_i) \equiv  P(X|h_i)$, since $X$ is conditionally independent of $d$ given $h_i$. I recall reading something like that in another textbook, but I've forgotten where. Is there any intuition for why this is so? Something along the lines of the trials are independent/the previous trial does not affect the next trial (except only how it hints at what the hypothesis might be)?

Comment: @information_interchange That *is* what I was getting at, and is, I think, implied by the authors writing "where we have assumed that each hypothesis determines a probability distribution over $X$." For intuition on conditional independence, think of this example. If an (unobserved) coin is heads, $X \sim N(0,1)$; tails, $X \sim N(1,1)$. Now, say that the coin is unfair and that you do not know the probability of heads, but you can observe that it does in fact turn up heads. (1/)

Comment: Would changing the probability of a heads change your understanding of the distribution of $X$? It wouldn't, because however likely or not a heads result is, you've observed what occurred and know the corresponding distribution. Helpful?

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for the follow-up and I have been thinking about what you said. I don't quite understand what you mean by heads is $ X∼N(0,1) $ while tails is $ X ~ N(1,1)$ . How can the probability of a head/tails be represented by a Normal Distribution, which is not bounded on the [0,1] interval? Shouldn't we specify different hypotheses for the same outcome?

Comment: Oh I think I see what you are saying! For example, So are you saying that if it IS heads, then X~N(0,1) , else if it IS tails, then X~N(1,1)? In that case, it makes sense: knowing the probability of getting a head is irrelevant after you already have gotten a head. I think a similar concept crops up in Bayes Networks in general and using d-separation.

Comment: @information_interchange Exactly!